# What to do when user is offline?

Tags: user-expectation, experience, disable

I am working on an app where there is a function for driving directions - the user chooses their preferred map app (Google Maps, Apple Maps, Waze), then they are sent to that app with the address populated.

I am currently working through offline behaviors. When their device is offline (no signal, no wifi), there is limited locally stored info, but no map. What would be the best experience for a user in offline mode when it comes to the Driving Directions button in our app?

1. Driving Directions button would be disabled and/or link to an in-app message telling the user they are offline, and let them know what in-app data can be available while offline.
2. Go ahead and let the user click the link for Driving Directions, taking them to the app of their choice, where they would get an offline message from that app. The only possible value here would be in the rare instance that a user had some offline map data downloaded.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Keep in mind that many map services also allow the downloading of maps locally so that it can work in offline mode as well.

Answer (score 3):

**My vote would be to send them to the mapping app and let the app handle the connectivity issues.** The reason is that the issues might be temporary, and the user could come back online within seconds. If that's the case, they'll want to be as close to their user goal ("Find directions to the location where I need to go") as possible.